# What are the conditions for Genis to learn Stone Blast?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

What are the conditions for Genis to get Stone Blast? An [online guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gamecube/561316-tales-of-symphonia/faqs/32889) just says it happens when he reaches Level 3.

But he's been level 3 for a while... And I assume he gained the spell in battle, maybe after casting Fire Ball 50 times?

It seems like there's other such spells, like Wind Blade, which can be seen in the menu at Level 5. But seems to need 60 Fire Ball casts as well, to unlock. And possibly some number of Stone Blasts?

Sorta like how I have a LV4 Lloyd, with a blue Sonic Thrust in the Tech menu... Which IIRC, the AI doesn't use until it's somehow unlocked in battle?

Answer (score 2):

Different sources say the same, the only requirement for **Stone Blast** is to reach level 3, as you can see below.

[image]

What needs another spell to be cast specific number of times are Mid and Advanced spells.

[Here](https://aselia.fandom.com/wiki/ToS_-_Genis_Sage:_Techs) you can find other useful tables with spells and their requirements.

Regarding the *blue spell*:

> The spells in blue means that you have the prerequisites fulfilled but needs to randomly unlock it in battle. Using a prerequisite skill or an A attack (for melee techs only) will unlock the skill. The randomness and likelihood of unlocking a skill is based on the character's Luck stat.

Source, [Neoseeker forum](https://www.neoseeker.com/forums/4182/t606181-spells-in-blue/).

Comment: What does it mean, when a spell is in the Tech menu in blue letters or something? I think it was?

Comment: @Malady sorry I don't own the game so I can't tell, the only thing I can do is report information :/

Comment: Thanks anyway! Hopefully this helps someone get more info?

Comment: @Malady I made an edit!

Comment: Now upvoting! And likely you'll get the checkmark! ... And it was on that guide I linked too. I just didn't search for it... Ah well.